# express-session on saving on routes

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I've server.js, it is a startup entry point, i declare the session like this

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const db = require('./database/db');
const session = require('express-session');

const category = require('./category/category');
const threads = require('./threads/threads');
const posts = require('./posts/posts');

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // replace with your domain
    credentials: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
    session({
        secret: 'bkepcraymanAbcd1234', // Replace with your own secret
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { secure: false }
    })
);

// Routes
app.use('/api/category', category);
app.use('/api/threads', threads);
app.use('/api/posts', posts);
```

in thread.js, i have this method for testing

```
router.post('/views/:threadId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { threadId } = req.params;
        req.session.test = '123123123123';
        console.log(req.session.test);
        //req.session.viewedThreads = [];
        //req.session.viewedThreads['thread_' + threadId] = true;
        const array = {[threadId]:true};
        req.session.viewedThreads.push(array);

        req.session.save(err => {
            if(err) {
                // handle error
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                // send response
                res.send('Session saved');
            }
        });
```

i call the /threads/views/16 at first time,
it will log 123123123123,
then i comment out req.session.test = '123123123123';
it will log undefined

the session not saving the variable, anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Warning** The default server-side session storage, [`MemoryStore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memorystore)

The session data is stored in memory. So, if you modify the code and restart the server(process), the session data will be gone.

You can pick another storage from [Compatible Session Stores](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores) to persist the session data in a database or a local file.

- [session-file-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store)
- [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo)